# MongoDB Loop Query

Tags: mongodb, loops

```
db.fs.files.distinct( "metadata.user" )
[
    "5027",
    "6048",
    "6049",
]
```

The below X represents where I would like the numbers from the above query to appear. 
    db.fs.files.find({ 'metadata.user' : X,  'metadata.folder' : 'inbox' }).count()

I'm trying to find a way to iterate through each of the users in the first query and count the total number of results in the second query. Is there an easy way to craft this query in the MongoDB Shell?

The output I would be looking for would be (just looking for pure numbers):

```
User Inbox
5027 9872
6048 12
6049 125
```

**Update:**

I was able to accomplish something pretty close to what I was looking for:

```
# for x in $(psql -d ****** postgres -c "select user_name from users where   user_name ~ '^[0-9]+$' order by user_name;" | tail -n +3 | head -n -2); do mongo vmdb --quiet --eval "db.fs.files.find({ 'metadata.user' : '$x'}).count()"; done| sort -nr

1381
1073
982
```

However, i'm missing out on the username part. The point is to generate a list of users with the number of messages in their mailboxes.

Comment: Tell us what you already tried and what is not working. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: var x = db.fs.files.distinct( "metadata.user" )

forEach(function(x){db.fs.files.find({ 'metadata.user' : x,  'metadata.folder' : 'inbox' })})  Fri Jun 17 11:58:25 exec error: (shell):1 ReferenceError: forEach is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
var myCursor = db.collection.find( "metadata.user" );

while(myCursor.hasNext()) {
  db.fs.files.find({ 'metadata.user' : X,  'metadata.folder' : 'inbox' }).count();
}
```

Comment: Fri Jun 17 12:00:02 exec error: (shell):1 TypeError: Object 5027,6048,6049 has no method 'hasNext'
while(myCursor.hasNext()) {
               ^

Comment: What is your mongo version ?

Comment: MongoDB shell version: 2.2.3

Comment: I realize this is probably a bit older- but I wouldn't get to make the call on upgrading.

Comment: Tested on a different machine: MongoDB shell version: 2.6.7
2016-06-17T12:34:04.321-0400 TypeError: Object 120,207,300,302,304,309 has no method 'hasNext'

Comment: Mongo version is not the problem. The problem is distinct function. It looks like only find() creates cursor. I dont see any example where distinct is creating cursor.